# Getting an NRE when using delegates in Unity

Tags: c#, unity

I have a game where I have balls bouncing and you shoot them. Since I need a way to end the level when the player shoots all the balls I though I would create a game controller script which will register to an event from the ball script. In the awake function in the ball script I'm using this:

```
if (this.gameObject.tag == "SmallestBall") {
        if(!touchedTheRope) {
            countBalls(false);
        }
    }
```

NOTE: In this code here I'm not performing a check if(event != null) then execute - because I already know there is a problem. In the game controller script in the awake function I'm using this code:

```
UniversalBallScript.countBalls += CountBalls;
```

In the method CountBalls in game controller script I have Debug.Log to print out the number of balls. Because the small balls are being instantiated I first just performed a test where I check if the tag == "SmallestBall" and I just Debug.Log in the console, it gives me 28 small balls, but when I use the code above to call the event (if (this.gameObject.tag == "SmallestBall") etc... I get 24 balls and 4 null reference exceptions. I dont know if it has something to do with the fact that the small balls are being instantiated but I'm calling event registration in Awake and I also call that event in the Awake function, I have also tried to put this code:

```
if (this.gameObject.tag == "SmallestBall") {
        if(!touchedTheRope) {
            countBalls(false);
        }
    }
```

In OnEnable and OnDisable and its the same problem, I get 24 balls and 4 null reference exceptions. And BTW the null reference exceptions appear first and after that other 24 balls pass regularly. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I have fixed the issue on how to track the balls, I just used a static variable. But if someone knows the answer on why this is happening I would love to hear it.

Comment: Since you don't have any answer yet, if the scope of the question changed, you should update the text of the question to specify only that, this way we'll have a better question with a better answer :)

Comment: The scope of the question did not change, the question is the same, why can my script register as a delegate for 24 objects and cant register for 4 objects, I just said I found another way to do it, but if there is a solution for this I can still use it.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Is there a chance you can ask it again in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, could it be because the dependent script is being activated on awake as well as it's parent? Maybe try placing the initialization stuff for the child script in the start method instead.

Comment: The script does not have a parent, I need to do it in awake because the balls that I'm instantiating need be deactivated after being instantiated, and I need to do both e.g register as a delegate and deactivate objects, I think that maybe that is the problem because I register as a delegate in one script and deactivate the script that I am the delegate for in awake, but it does not make sense that 24 objects get a delegate and 4 objects dont :S

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over the order in which scripts are `Awake()`ned.

In general, a script should only reference itself during `Awake()`. Any code which relies on other game objects already being initialized should be in the `Start()` event.

Comment: "No control" might overstate it a bit. When it's two distinct scripts communicating, we can ensure one gets Awake() first by putting it earlier in the [Script Execution Order](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html). This should probably be a solution of last resort though, since Philipp's suggestion of moving the dependent behaviour to Start() solves it more simply. As a general rule, I put all my initialisation in Start so that I can fall back to Awake when I really need to preempt something. ;)